# Disable scrolling on UICollectionView

Tags: ios, scroll, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I would like to implement a UICollectionView, where the user is denied the ability to scroll to the next item, but it is still partially visible.

I want it to be bouncing like when a UIScrollView reaches an end.

Comment: u mean, the user can only try to drag the edge of the other cell which doesnt move ?

Comment: The user can try to drag to the next item, but it reacts as if it was the end of a uiscrollview

Comment: how many cells r visible to the user ?

Comment: The current one, the previous and the next one both partially

Comment: A UICollectionView is just a UIScrollview, so I expect if you set its contentSize to the size of the view, you would get the behaviour that you describe.